# How to interchanging the option element in Multiple select using javascript

Tags: javascript

(move up or down the option element)
How to interchanging the option element in Multiple select using javascript
Ex.

                  Mail Id
                  First Name
                  Last Name
                  User Type
                  City
                  Letter
                
it display like this
Mail Id
First Name
Last Name
User Type
City

i want change the option like
Mail Id
Last Name
First Name
User Type
City

how can interchanging options using javascript

Comment: Can't be interchanged except recreation !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (but the least optimized) is to get all, rearrange (send the id or a number or something to the function) and then recreate the element.

The optimized version is to use insertBefore(element, document.getElementById("elementcontainer").child), where child is the child before you want to insert.